# Ruby on Rails: Do you recommend using Observers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I notice it's used primarily for sending emails. Let's say I want to send an email after every comment is created.

Is using Observers really necessary when you could just place the Mailer.deliver_email(user) in your comments_controller.rb's create action instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For proper programming practices, yes. The observers decouple the code and make sure it stays maintainable.

Comment: Thanks James! It's great to learn from experts on Stack Overflow. Thank you so much.